# Child class private member called from Parent class public member

Tags: java

What is happening in the code below? Please explain the output:

```
class Parent{
    private void fun(){
        System.out.println("parent fun\n");
    }
    public void accessFun(){
        System.out.println(this);
        this.fun();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    private void fun(){
        System.out.println("child fun");
    }
}

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child a = new Child();
        Parent b = new Parent();
        Parent c = new Child();
        a.accessFun();
        b.accessFun();
        c.accessFun();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Child@7960847b

parent fun

Parent@3b192d32

parent fun

Child@16f65612

parent fun
```

Why the line this.fun() is not giving compile-time error?

I think fun is a private member in Child class and therefore can't be accessed from outside the Child class(from public member of it's Parent class).

Why Parent class version of fun() is being called by this.fun()? Note **this** refers to child class object.

Comment: it's not accessed form the outside of the parent class, it's the accessFun() who has the access to fun, this what how private members are used.

Comment: Yes, As Rajat Verma said, it's accessed inside parent class, not outside so it work without anyproblem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Private members are not inherited.**

I think this might be the key point that you are missing here. What this means is that `Child.fun` does not override `Parent.fun`. They are just two plain old methods that has nothing to do with each other.

When you call `accessFun`, control always goes into this bit of code in `Parent`:

```
public void accessFun(){
    System.out.println(this);
    this.fun(); <---- here
}
```

Now, since we are now inside `Parent`, we can access `fun`. And since `Parent.fun` is *not overridden*, it calls `Parent.fun` and not `Child.fun`.

> I think fun is a private member in child class and therefore can't be accessed from outside the class(may even from public member of it's Parent class).

That is a complete misunderstanding. if private members can't be accessed from outside of the class, not even through public methods, then they will be much less useful. Why even have them in the first place?

"Private members can only be accessed by *members* declared in the same class" is probably a better thing to remember.

Comment: Yes i understand that. But *this* is referring to child's object. Actually replace this.fun() by  this.bun() and change fun() in child class to bun() then output will be **cannot find bun()** and i am trying to say same should happen in the case discussed in question.

Comment: @HarshkiratSingh In the `bun` case, it cannot find `bun` because you are in the scope of the parent class, and parent classes simply knows nothing about child classes, not because `bun` is private.

Comment: @HarshkiratSingh Roughly the same thing happens in the `fun` case as well. When you call `this.fun()`, it checks if the method is overridden and since `Child.fun` does not override `Parent.fun`, it says "nope, `Parent.fun` is not overridden, so I will just call `Parent.fun`."

Comment: @HarshkiratSingh If you understand that much, then it's easier to explain. Because you are in the scope of the parent, you know nothing about `Child`, _unless what you are calling is overridden_, which in this case it is not. You simply cannot call `Child.fun` in `Parent.accessFun`, because `Child.fun` is invisible to `Parent`. And this has nothing to do with `private`. It is just because all classes don't know about their children.

Answer (score 0):

`private fun()` in Parent is called by `public accessFun()`  of same Parent class. And `public accessFun()` is called in `main()` of Test class.
Here accessFun() is public so it can be called from any where.
For example just like Pojo classes private members are accessed through public setters and getters

Answer (score 0):

The fun method in parent is private and the child fun() method is not overriding the parent fun() method. But the accessFun method is public so it can be called from the child class and is publicly accessible.

So when you call accessFun() method it will be calling the parent class fun() method. Not the child class fun() method as it is private. That is why you wont get an error.

Comment: What does this syntax do:  referenceType.methodName(); ? This is what i want to ask this.fun() should call fun() belonging to object referred by *this* and if this is so it should give error as fun() have private access in Child. Even if *this* refers to Child class object parent's fun is called why?

Comment: @HarshkiratSingh At compile time, `this` is always the current class you're writing in.

Answer (score 0):

> I think fun is a private member in child class and therefore can't be accessed from outside the class(may even from public member of it's Parent class).

Sometimes everything comes from "outside". The `main` call comes from outside for example.

If a private member can not be accessed from outside, it would always be dead code and this makes no sense.

The difference is the understanding from direct-access and indirect-access.

In all cases you call the method non-directly via the method `accessFun()`.